# use VS2008 express as VS2010 native toolkit

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010, c++-cli, toolkit

I'm about to switch computer and can't find my VS2008 installation disk.

I only use VS2008 as a native vc90 toolkit in VS2010 to compile an old C++/CLI wrapper assembly. (Haven't opened the VS2008 IDE since I installed VS2010)

Anyone know if it possible to use the c++ express version of VS2008 as vc90 toolkit in VS2010?

Answer (score 1):

I seem to recall that the full VC2008 compiler is bundled with some versions of the Platform SDK, unlike the express edition which IIRC has crippled optimizations.

Comment: This is just a small wrapper so optimizations is not an issue.